# Javafx TextFlow text wrapping issue when using ImageView

Tags: java, javafx

When I'm adding ImageView to the TextFlow element, the next Text element is starting at the bottom of an image. Is there a way to configure text wrapping so that text will start near the top and continue along the side while where is space?

Comment: TextFlow is really meant for only laying out Text children.  As far as I can tell, alignment of text relative to other nodes isn’t supported.  You may want to consider using a [WebView](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html) instead.